# Is there a way in R to replace a pattern only if it is preceded by letter?

Tags: r, regex

I have a string (more precisely a query) where I need to add some characters ("\n") at the end of all words between ''. The problem is that my string algo contains numbers between '', and they should remain unchanged. A simplified version of the beginning of the string follows:

```
"SELECT CASE WHEN V1 = '1' THEN 'word' WHEN V1 = '3' THEN 'another word' END"
```

And the desired result with the replacements would be:

```
"SELECT CASE WHEN V1 = '1' THEN 'word\n' WHEN V1 = '3' THEN 'another word\n' END"
```

I tried using gsub function, but I couldn`t figure out how to make it work the way I need. If I use:

```
gsub("' ", "\n' ", string)
```

The numbers are also replaced. Or if I use:

```
gsub("[a-z]' ", "\n' ", string)
```

I end up removing the last letter of the words.

Am I missing an obvious solution here? I`m quite new at programming, so I apreciate some help if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Capture as group (`(...)`) for the letter followed by the `'` and then use the backreference (`\\1`) of the group captured in the replacement.  In the OP's post, the letter was matched, but it was not captured and thus got removed in the output

```
gsub("([A-Za-z])' ", "\\1\n' ", string)
[1] "SELECT CASE WHEN V1 = '1' THEN 'word\n' WHEN V1 = '3' THEN 'another word\n' END"
```

#### data

```
string <- "SELECT CASE WHEN V1 = '1' THEN 'word' WHEN V1 = '3' THEN 'another word' END"
```

Comment: I believe OP needs `gsub("([A-Za-z])' ", "\\1\n' ", string)` to get the line break within `''`.